# Harddrive spinning down though time increased with hdparm

Tags: linux, hard-drive, power-management

I have an external harddrive connected via USB.
The usual method to set the spindown / standby time of harddrives seems to be using hdparm.

So I run `sudo hdparm -S 200 /dev/sdb` and get

```
/dev/sdb:  setting standby to 200 (16 minutes + 40 seconds)

SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  f0 00 01 00 50 40 c8 0a 00 00 00 00 00 1d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

I remember having tried this before without getting that extra message with SG_IO.
Now it seems that whatever value I set, the drive spins down after about a minute when idle.
It even spins up and down many times while working which introduces annoying delays and I also think it’d be better for the drive’s health to keep running.

I haven’t found a way to see if the value is really set, but I can do so for the APM (Advanced Power Management) level:

```
sudo hdparm -B 196 /dev/sdb    
/dev/sdb:
 setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xc4 (196)
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  f0 00 01 00 50 40 c4 0a 00 00 00 00 00 1d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
 APM_level  = 196

$ sudo hdparm -B /dev/sdb    
/dev/sdb:
 APM_level  = 196
```

The system is Arch Linux with kernel 3.17.6.

Why is the drive spinning down anyway? What can be done to avoid it?

#### Update

`hdparm` has the following option, but the result of the commands is the same:

> --prefer-ata12
>                 When  using the SAT (SCSI ATA Translation) protocol, hdparm normally prefers to use the 16-byte command format whenever possible.  But some USB drive enclosures don't work correctly with 16-byte commands.  This option
>                 can be used to force use of the smaller 12-byte command format with such drives.  hdparm will still revert to 16-byte commands for things that cannot be done with  the  12-byte  format  (e.g.  sector  accesses  beyond
>                 28-bits).

Comment: is your disk a WD Green drive, and do you have the idle3 package installed? https://www.gamingonlinux.com/articles/western-digital-green-hdd-how-to-stop-them-dying-on-you.4814/page=1

Comment: No, it’s a `TOSHIBA External USB 3.0`.